# Is it possible to achieve this R Plotly example for Python?

Tags: python, panel, plotly-python

The following code makes a plotly line plot, where you can drag a vertical line and a red marker will follow to the new values of the intersection point. However this code is in R and using the Plotly and the Shiny libraries, and I was wondering if it is possible to achieve the same with Plotly and Panel for python?

I found the example from the last comment here:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/sliding-a-point-on-a-plot-rather-than-sliderinput-to-update-plot-in-shiny/16405/8

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("p"),
  verbatimTextOutput("event")
)

x <- seq(-10, 10)
y <- rnorm(length(x))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$p <- renderPlotly({
    
    d <- event_data("plotly_relayout", source = "trajectory")
    
    selected_point <- if (!is.null(d[["shapes[0].x0"]])) {
      xint <- d[["shapes[0].x0"]]
      xpt <- x[which.min(abs(x - xint))]
      list(x = xpt, y = y[which(x == xpt)])
    } else {
      list(x = 1, y = y[which(x == 1)])
    }
    
    plot_ly(color = I("red"), source = "trajectory") %>%
      add_lines(x = x, y = y) %>%
      add_markers(x = selected_point$x, y = selected_point$y) %>%
      layout(
        shapes = list(
          type = "line", 
          line = list(color = "gray", dash = "dot"),
          x0 = selected_point$x, 
          x1 = selected_point$x,
          y0 = 0,
          y1 = 1,
          yref = "paper"
        )
      ) %>%
      config(editable = TRUE)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension('plotly')
import plotly.express as pex
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x=list(range(-10,10))
y=np.random.normal(x)

fig = pex.line(x=x, y=y)
vline = fig.add_vline(x=3)

plot = pn.pane.Plotly(fig,config={'modeBarButtonsToAdd':['drawline','drawopen','eraseshape','path','drawclosedpath',
                                               'drawcircle','drawrect',
                                                ], 'doubleClick': 'reset', 'responsive': True, 'displaylogo': False, 'editable':True})
                                                
col = pn.Row(plot)
col

d = dict(plot.relayout_data)
if d['shapes[0].x0'] != None:
    xint = d['shapes[0].x0']
    selected_point = dict(x=xint, y=np.interp(xint, x, y))
else:
    selected_point = dict(x = 1, y=np.interp(1, x, y))
```

So I guess my main problem is how to get the marker to follow when moving/dragging the vertical line?